# Doubt in understanding 6.3 form Rudin functional analysis

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, proof-explanation

I was reading sec 6.3 form Rudin Functional analysis
[image]

[image]

I do not understand why highlighted set belong to $\beta$?

$D(\Omega)$ is test function space on open set

Please help me

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Are you tried to say "I do not understand highlighted set , which belongs to $\beta$", or "I do not understand why the highlighted set belongs to $\beta$".  In either case, it would help if you wrote out the definition of $\mathscr D(\Omega)$ for us.

Comment: By your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3510982/81360), it seems that $\mathscr D(\Omega)$ is the set of all $C^\infty$ functions over $\Omega$ with compact support.

Comment: Yes Sir.That is defination Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $S = \{\phi \in \mathscr{D}(\Omega): |\phi(x_n)| < c_n\; n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is obviously convex and balanced.

Now take arbitrary compact $K \subset \Omega$ and consider $S \bigcap \mathscr{D}_K$. Since sequence $x_n$ does not have a limit point in $\Omega$ then $K \bigcap \{x_n:\; n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ is finite because $K$ is compact. Let $\{x_{n_1},\dots,x_{n_m}\} = K \bigcap \{x_n:\; n \in \mathbb{N}\}$. Then $S \bigcap \mathscr{D}_K = \{\phi \in \mathscr{D}_K: |\phi(x_{n_k})| < c_{n_k}\; k = 1,\dots,m\}$. This set is obviously open in $\mathscr{D}_K$ since it is a finite intersection of open sets $\bigcap\limits_{k = 1}^{m} \{\phi \in \mathscr{D}_K: |\phi(x_{n_k})| < c_{n_k}\} = S \bigcap \mathscr{D}_K \in \tau_K$.

By definition 6.3 (b) $S$ belongs to $\beta$.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir