# Topology generated in the test space leads to same convergence

Tags: general-topology, analysis, distribution-theory

In the test space $K$ of all infinitely differentiable compact supported functions, let $N_{0}$ be the neighborhood base at zero consisting of all sets of the form

$$U_{\gamma_{0}, \ldots , \gamma_{n}} = \{ \phi: \phi \in K, |\phi (x)| < \gamma_{0}(x), \ldots , |\phi^{(n)}(x)| < \gamma_{n}(x) \text{ for all x} \}$$

for some positive functions $\gamma_{0}, \ldots, \gamma_{n}$ continuous on $(- \infty, \infty)$. Prove that the topology generated in $K$ by $N_{0}$ leads to the same kind of convergence in $K$ as in Definition 1.

Definition 1. A sequence $(\phi_{n})$ of functions in $K$ is said to converge to a function $\phi \in K$ iff.

(i) there exists an interval outside which all the functions $\phi_{n}$ vanish; and

(ii) The sequence $(\phi_{n}^{(k)})$ of the kth derivative converges uniformly on this interval to $\phi^{(k)}$ for every $k = 0, 1, 2, \ldots$ .

I am lost in how to approach this problem. What I know is how a base generates a topology, namely a set $U$ is open iff. for each $x \in U$ there is a base element $B$ such that $x \in B$ and $B \subseteq U$.

**Edit**: So I am not sure whether I have taken the right approach to the problem but what I have done is to assume that $(\phi_{n}) \rightarrow \phi$ in the topology $\tau$ generated by $N_{0}$. And now I want to show that this will be the same as Definition 1 above.

By definition of convergence in a topological space this means that for every open neighborhood $U$ of $\phi$ there is an $N$ such that for each $n > N$ we have $\phi_{n} \in U$.

But this means that $U$ is open and hence by the base $N_{0}$ there is a base element $U_{\gamma_{0}, \ldots , \gamma_{n}}$ s. t. all $\phi, \phi_{n} \in U_{\gamma_{0}, \ldots , \gamma_{n}}$.

This means that $\phi \in K$ and $|\phi (x)| < \gamma_{0}(x), \ldots , |\phi^{(k)}(x)| < \gamma_{k}(x) \text{ for all x}$.

Similarly, $\phi_{n} \in K$ and $|\phi_{n} (x)| < \gamma_{n, 0}(x), \ldots , |\phi_{n}^{(k)}(x)| < \gamma_{n, k}(x) \text{ for all x}$,

for some positive functions $\gamma$ continuous on $(- \infty, \infty)$.

But since all $\phi_{n} \in K$, means that all $\phi_{n}$ are compactly supported and hence they vanish in some interval. This is condition (i) in Definition 1.

To show (ii) we must show that $(\phi_{n}^{(k)}) \rightarrow \phi^{(k)}$ uniformly. In other words, for all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $N$ such that for all $n > N$ and all $x$ we have $|\phi_{n}^{(k)} - \phi^{(k)}| < \epsilon$.

And I am lost here but it does seem that I can somehow use the inequalities bounded by the functions $\gamma$ to show uniform convergence perhaps by the triangle inequality but I get lost in the inequalities.

Hopefully my approach and understanding of the problem is correct so far. Any suggestions and hints are welcomed.

**Edit 2**: I also thought about what if the functions $\gamma$ were uniform continuous since they are continuous. But continuity does not imply uniform continuity in general. However, continuity on a closed bounded interval does indeed imply uniform continuity. I thought about using the compact support of the functions $\phi$ and then perhaps restricting the functions $\gamma$ to this closed and bounded interval. Not sure if this helps.

Comment: what you describe is not the correct way to define the topology of $K$, which BTW nobody calls $K$, but rather $\mathscr{D}(\mathbb{R})$ or $C_{\rm c}^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam The problem is that the literature for the course is Kolmogorov and Fomin Introductory Real Analysis and that is where the notation and the ideas are from. Any literature you can recommend with standard notation and which is standard in teaching?

Comment: the topology of the space $K$ is entirely explained from scratch here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510982/doubt-in-understanding-space-d-omega/3511753#3511753 you need to follow the steps as a series of exercises that you have to work out on the side, but basically it's all there. Then you can look at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234025/why-is-multiplication-on-the-space-of-smooth-functions-with-compact-support-cont/234503#234503 for an example of use of the topology