# Convolution of Distribution with smooth function

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory, convolution

I meet an exercise in my homework:
Let $f\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, show that the biliner map $(f,g)\mapsto f*g $ is continuous in $f$ and $g$, respectively.

I have proved that for any fixed $f\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, if $g_{i}\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ such that $g_{i}\to 0$ in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, then $f*g_{i}\to 0$ in $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but I don't know how to prove that for any fixd $g\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $f_{i}\to 0$ in $\mathcal{D'}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ then $f_{i}*g\to 0$ in $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^n)$. **Is this conclusion correct?**

**Here is my approach:** To prove  $f_{i}*g\to 0$ in $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, we need to show that, for any compact set $K\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, and any multi-index $\alpha$, 
$$\sup_{x\in K}|\partial^{\alpha}(f_{i}\ast g)|=\sup_{x\in K}|f_{i}\ast \partial^{\alpha}g|
=\sup_{x\in K}|\langle f_{i}(y),\partial_{x}^{\alpha}g(x-y)\rangle|\to 0$$
holds for fixed $g\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ as $i\to +\infty$. But we only have $f_{i}\to 0$ in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, it seems we can only show that, for any fixed $x\in K$, 
$$ |\langle f_{i}(y),\partial_{x}^{\alpha}g(x-y)\rangle|\to 0$$
for $i\to +\infty$.

Can someone help me with the question above? Thank you very much!

Comment: You write "$f*g_{i}\to 0$ in $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^n)$". Does $\mathcal{E}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ denote the space of compactly supported distributions? If so, $f * g \not\in \mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ in general for $f \in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g \in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n).$

Comment: For a function $g\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and a distribution $f\in  \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ , I think we can deduce that $f*g\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, the space $\mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ is the $ C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ edowed with some Frechet topology. Why $f*g\notin \mathcal{E}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for $f\in \mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $g\in \mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R}^n)$?

Comment: Ah, sorry. I thought of $\mathcal{E}'$ when you wrote $\mathcal{E}.$

Comment: It would help general readers to understand if the definitions of $\mathcal D$, $\mathcal D'$ and $\mathcal E$ are presented.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment so posted as answer.

Although artificial, this is an excellent question.

The convolution map $\mathcal{D}'\times\mathcal{D}\rightarrow \mathcal{E}$ is of course bilinear but is **not** continuous. It is only *hypocontinuous*.
Here $\mathcal{D}$ has its standard topology whose explicit definition textbooks avoid. $\mathcal{E}$ is given the Frechet topology as in the OP.
Next, $\mathcal{D}'$ must be given the strong topology, not the weak-$\ast$.
Finally, $\mathcal{D}'\times\mathcal{D}$ is given the product topology.
Then for fixed $g$ and $\alpha$, the test functions $y\mapsto \partial^{\alpha}g(x-y)$, where $x$ ranges over the compact $K$, form a bounded set in $\mathcal{D}$. Therefore
$$
\rho(f)=\sup_{x\in K} |\langle f(y), \partial^{\alpha}g(x-y)\rangle_y|
$$
is a continuous seminorm on $\mathcal{D}'$ by the very definition of the correct (strong) topology. So $\rho(f_i)\rightarrow 0$ is included in the package of saying that $f_i$ converges to zero.

Now if one follows textbooks, and puts the weak-$\ast$ topology on $\mathcal{D}'$, then one indeed gets into the kind of trouble pinpointed by the OP.

For the topology of $\mathcal{D}$ see: [Doubt in understanding Space $D(\Omega)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510982/doubt-in-understanding-space-d-omega/3511753#3511753)

Answer (score 1):

The conclusion you are trying to draw will not hold in the weak-* topology on the space of distributions and Abdelmalek Abdesselam has correctly pointed out the issue: the convolution mapping is discontinuous. While their post gives the reason for continuity in a stronger topology, a counterexample for discontinuity in the setting of the weaker topology is not given.

This topic has been the subject of study in

> J. Larcher, *Multiplications and Convolutions in L. Schwartz' Spaces of Test Functions and Distributions and their Continuity*, [arXiv:1209.4174](https://arxiv.org/abs/1209.4174).

A counterexample is given in Proposition 2, namely to the test space $\mathcal{D} := C^\infty_c$ of smooth functions with compact support, paired with the space $\mathcal{E}'$ of distributions with compact support, with convolution mapping $*_{\mathcal{D}}:C^\infty_c \times \mathcal{E}' \to C^\infty_c$. This is stronger than the case of $*_{\mathcal{E}} : (\mathcal{E} = C^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n), \mathcal{E}') \to \mathcal{E}$, wherein $\mathcal{E}'$ carries the topology of seminorms $p_{m,K}(f) := \sup_{x \in K, |\alpha| \leq m} |\partial^\alpha f(x)|$, for $K \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ compact, since we have continuous embeddings $\mathcal{D} \hookrightarrow \mathcal{E}$ and $\mathcal{D} \times \mathcal{E}' \hookrightarrow \mathcal{E} \times \mathcal{E}'$. It's also stronger to consider $*_{\mathcal{D}}$ because the seminorms on $\mathcal{D}$ are continuous norms, while $\mathcal{E}$ does not carry a continuous norm (see the discussion at the beginning of section 3.1).

An alternate argument to deal with $*_{\mathcal{E}}$ can therefore be given more quickly and is stated after Proposition 2: if $T := \delta_0 \in \mathcal{E}'$, then $f *_{\mathcal{E}} \delta_0$ is the evaluation map, but this is only continuous when $\mathcal{E}$ is normed, which we know is not the case for $\mathcal{E} = C^\infty$ with the above seminorms.

The manuscript tabulates the various combinations of spaces and multiplication and convolution operations among them and either proves continuity or discontinuity, along with providing many references.