# The inductive limit toplogies on $D \left( \mathbb{R}^n \right)$ obtained from different inductive systems

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

I have been reading about inductive limit topology from the book "A Course in Functional Analysis" by J B Conway. My motivation for reading this was to understand Fourier Transforms and Distribution Theory given in the book "Integral Geometry and Radon Transforms" by S. Helgason.

For reference to this question, I will be using the following definition of inductive limit topology:

> **Definition** (Inductive system): A pair $(X_i, \left\lbrace X_i : i \in I \right\rbrace)$ is an inductive system if $X$ is a vector space, each $X_i$ is a linear manifold (vector subspace) of $X$, each $X_i$ has a topology $\mathscr{T}_i$ which is locally convex such that
>
> 1. $I$ is a directed set and whenever $i \leq j$ (with $i, j \in I$), we have $X_i \subseteq X_j$.
> 2. Whenever $i \leq j$ and $U_j \in \mathscr{T}_j$, we have $U_j \cap X_i \in \mathscr{T}_i$.
> 3. $X = \bigcup\limits_{i \in I} X_i$.

The book by J B Conway gives the topology on $D \left( \mathbb{R}^n \right)$, the set of all compactly supported smooth functions, by defining for each compact set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$, the family of seminorms on $D_K \left( \mathbb{R}^n \right) := \left\lbrace \phi \in D \left( \mathbb{R}^n \right) | \text{supp } \phi \subseteq K \right\rbrace$ as

$$p_{k, m} \left( \phi \right) = \sup \left\lbrace \left| \phi^{\left( \alpha \right)} \left( x \right) \right| : \left| \alpha \right| \leq m, x \in K \right\rbrace.$$

Here, $\alpha = \left\lbrace \alpha_1, \alpha_2, \cdots, \alpha_n \right\rbrace \in \left( \mathbb{N} \cup \left\lbrace 0 \right\rbrace \right)^n$, and $\left| \alpha \right| = \sum\limits_{i = 1}^{n} \alpha_i$. Also, we have the notation

$$\phi^{\left( \alpha \right)} = \dfrac{\partial^{\left| \alpha \right|} \phi}{\partial^{\alpha_1} x_1 \partial^{\alpha_2} x_2 \cdots \partial^{\alpha_n} x_n}.$$

I have verified that this indeed gives an inductive limit topology on $D \left( \mathbb{R}^n \right)$.

However, in the book by Helgason, the author defines the family of seminorms as

$$p_{K, m} \left( \phi \right) = \sum\limits_{\left| \alpha \right| \leq m} \sup \left\lbrace \left| \phi^{\alpha} \left( x \right) \right| : x \in K \right\rbrace.$$

My question is that are these two topologies different? Or are they equivalent? I believe that they are equivalent, but I am not quite getting the idea to prove it.

Comment: Two questions: in the definition of $p_{K,m}$, are you missing an absolute value? Have you already seen that both spaces are complete?

Comment: @Caffeine: I have edited the aboslute value. As for the second question, no, I have not seen that they are both complete. How would that help?

Comment: Once you have proved that they are complete, you can easily prove that they are [Frechet spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space). From that you can use the usual machinery (i.e. closed graph theorem and open map) to prove that the identity (from one topology to the other) is a homeomorphism.

Comment: @AniruddhaDeshmukh: Please see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510982/doubt-in-understanding-space-d-omega/3511753#3511753

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have an inequality like :
$$p_{K,m}^{\rm{Conway}} \leqslant p_{K,m}^{\rm{Helgason}}\leqslant C_{n,m} p_{K,m}^{\rm{Conway}}$$

where $C_{n,m}$ is the number of multi-indices with $|\alpha|\leq m$.

This should be enough to show directly that the open sets of both topologies are the same