# Are space of test functions and distributions normed spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, distribution-theory

I am asking myself the following question:

> Are space of test functions $\mathcal D$ and the space of distributions $\mathcal D'$ normed spaces (or even Banach spaces)?

**My thought.** I think that the answer is YES since I intuitively see that it is possible to define the norms in $\mathcal D'$. For examples, let $T\in \mathcal D'$, we may define the norm for $T$ as follows

$$||T||_{\mathcal D'}= \sup_{f\in \mathcal D: ||f||_{\infty} \leq 1} |T(f)|$$

or

$$||T||_{\mathcal D'}= \sup_{f\in \mathcal D: ||f||_{L^2} \leq 1} |T(f)|.$$

However, when I google I see that many papers try to put $\mathcal D'$ and $\mathcal D$ in some bigger Banach spaces than themselves, see e.g. [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.02949).

So I am really confusing. Am I right?

Comment: These are norms but they don't have anything to do with the standard topology on $\mathcal D'$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy do you mean the norms $||.||_\infty$ and $||.||_{L^2}$ are not norms associating with topology of $\mathcal D$, then the norm $||.||_{\mathcal D'}$ defined like above is not norm of $\mathcal D'$ w.r.t. the standard topology of $\mathcal D'$. So is there available norm corresponding to the topology of $\mathcal D$?

Comment: No, there is no such norm. BTW every vector space has a norm so producing some norm is of no use.

Comment: The answer is No. To learn the topology of $\mathcal{D}$ see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510982/doubt-in-understanding-space-d-omega/3511753#3511753

Comment: Also, I don't see the benefit of the imbedding into larger Banach spaces. The spaces $\mathcal{D}$, $\mathcal{D}'$ with standard topologies are much better than any Banach space one can find on the market.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam yeah thank you I will look at it, thank you so much!