# Understanding why the space of test functions is not Frechet

Tags: general-topology, partial-differential-equations, topological-vector-spaces

There are several questions+answers on this site demonstrating that the topology of $\mathcal D(\mathbb R)$, the space of smooth compactly supported test functions on $\mathbb R$, is not Frechet (and indeed not even sequential). However, they deal with the [first definition of Frechet spaces on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space#Invariant_metric_definition), whereas I am more used to using the [second definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space#Countable_family_of_seminorms_definition) in terms of a countable family of seminorms. Specifically, I want to understand which of the three criteria in the second Wikipedia definition fail for $\mathcal D ( \mathbb R)$. Why can't we use $\|\phi\|_k = \|D_k \phi\|_\infty$ as the relevant family of seminorms? And isn't this family complete, provided that all test functions are supported in the same compact interval?

Comment: The family of seminorms $\phi{K, n}(f)=\max_{1\leq j\leq n}\{\sup_{x\in K}|D^jf(x)|\}$ for each $K$ compact is complete in each $K$. the issue is the glue all those seminorms for different compact sets that cover $\mathbb{R}$. The inductive topology procedure does that. See for example Rudin's FA book, chapter  6.

Answer (score 1):

The $\|D_k\phi\|_{\infty}$ *do not* define the topology of $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$. To see an "explicit" and obviously non-countable collection of seminorms which do define the topology of $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$, look at Example 3 in my answer

[Doubt in understanding Space $\mathscr D(\Omega)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510982/doubt-in-understanding-space-mathscr-d-omega/3511753#3511753)