# What is the easiest way to define the canonical $LF$-topology?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, definition, distribution-theory

There are many ways to define the canonical $LF$-topology on $C^{\infty}_c$, as explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaces_of_test_functions_and_distributions).

Understanding that none of them is particularly easy, **which method for defining the topology is the simplest, and why?**

Comment: Btw remove the `.m` from mobile Wikipedia links when posting from your phone. Phone users would be automatically redirected to the mobile page but PC users are not automatically redirected to the PC page

Comment: @Sam It's not clear what you mean by "simplest" in this context. I'm sure you can determine yourself which is the definition that can be explained most quickly, so that's probably not what you mean. Are you looking for a definition that is easy to understand or one that is easy to use in practice? If you mean the latter, then what exactly are you doing with this topology?

Comment: @Sam If you're looking for some kind of intuitive way to understand the LF-topology on $C_c^\infty$, perhaps it is best that you state this explicitly in your question.

Comment: I think I already answered this question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510982/doubt-in-understanding-space-mathscr-d-omega/3511753#3511753