# Countable family of norms and seminorms

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, topological-vector-spaces, complete-spaces, frechet-space

In volume 4 of Gelfand and Vilenkin they study countably normed spaces. I assume a definition for a countably normed space was given in an earlier volume, but I do not have access to them and I could not find a definition online. How are these spaces defined and how are their topologies constructed?

Judging by the name I am guessing that we have a countable family of norms $\{\|\cdot\|_n\}$. Does a basis for this topology consist of sets of the form
$$N_{i_1, \ldots, i_n, \epsilon} = \{x \mid \|x\|_{i_m} < \epsilon, m \leq n\}?$$

My second question is that on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fr%C3%A9chet_space) one of the requirements for a topological vector space to be a Frechet space is that it is complete with respect to a family of seminorms. But how is completeness defined for a *family* of norms or seminorms? Do we require anything more than each Cauchy sequence converging with respect to any seminorm/norm in the family? Must these limits agree?

Comment: Given a countable family of seminorms $\|\cdot\|_n$, you can construct a pseudo-metric via $d(x,y) = \sum_{n} \frac{ \min\{ \|x-y\|_n, 1\}}{2^n}$. Once you have this pseudo-metric, you get both the topology and the definition of a Cauchy sequence.

Comment: And for reference, this is p16 in [Vol.2](https://archive.org/details/gelfand-shilov-generalized-functions-vol-2-spaces-of-fundamental-and-generalized-functions/page/15/mode/2up) (found the archive.org link on [this](https://mirtitles.org/2022/01/04/generalized-functions-vols-1-6-gelfand-shilov-graev-vilenkin-pyatetskii-shapiro/) page).

Comment: @RhysSteele Thank you. I am aware of that fact but I was interested if one can define it directly from the seminorms.

Comment: for a brief definition of the topology from a collection of seminorms see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3510982/doubt-in-understanding-space-mathscr-d-omega/3511753#3511753 in particular the $N_{i_1,\ldots,i_n,\epsilon}$ are not a basis of the topology but a neighborhood basis of the origin. To get a basis for the topology you need all the translates of these sets. In the particular situation at hand the completeness amounts to: for each sequence $(x_n)$ which is Cauchy for each $\|\cdot\|_m$ (obvious analogous definition as in normed space), there exists $x$...

Comment: ...such that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\|x_n-x\|_m=0$ for all $m$.

Comment: @AbdelmalekAbdesselam Thank you very much!